# C# How to determine if a date is within 180 days of now

Tags: c#, date

How can I determine if a date is within 180 days?

I've been playing with DateTime.Compare below and using date1 +180 days (date1 is 28th August 2009 13:12)

```
DateTime.Compare(**date1**.AddDays(180), now)
```

Is this correct?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 10):

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt1).Days <= 180
```

Comment: `dt2.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days <= 180`

Comment: @Developer Art: the order is important

Comment: @Vlad: date1 lies in the past (28.08.2009), which is why it needs to be the argument, otherwise the Days returned will be negative.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (Math.Abs(DateTime.Now.Subtract(date1).Days) <= 180)
{
    ...
}
```

This will let you know if `date1` is within 180 days IN EITHER DIRECTION of right now - past or future.  If you only need into the past, go with [Developer Art](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151323/developer-art)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320037/c-how-to-determine-if-a-date-is-within-180-days-of-now/2320051#2320051).